# I cannot use groupby with a dataframe based on lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe df of three columns "id", "nodes_set", "description" where "nodes_set" is a list of of strings.

I am trying to split it into groups based on their values of sequences as follows:

```
df_by_nodes_set = df.groupby('nodes_set')
list(df_by_nodes_set)
```

I think the problem lies in the fact that I am trying to use groupby with lists, but I am not sure how to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, but if you need to group by a list, then that list can be converted into a hash or simply concatenate the elements to get an id, like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[i, list(range(i)),'sample ' + str(i)] for i in range(5)] , columns = ["id", "nodes_set", "description"])

nodes_set_key = df['nodes_set'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x)))
df.groupby(nodes_set_key).last()
```

Here is the code output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is what I suspected. I was wondering if there is another way to do that, mainly because I really do not care about the order of the sequence. That means that I will have to order the strings first, create the hashable and perform groupby.

Comment: If "id" is unique for each list, then you could use that as the groupby key. Alternatively, if the list of items is long you could convert it into md5 digest like this `import hashlib; nodes_set_key = df['nodes_set'].apply(lambda x: hashlib.md5('_'.join(map(str, x)).encode('utf8')).hexdigest())`